# DataTable Image to MemorySteam Error: 'MemoryStream' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#, image, datatable, memorystream

**Overview**

I'm trying to pull out 1 record from a datatable and display it in my PictureBox (pbCharacter)

**Issue:**

I have a datatable that is returned from a function GetCompetitionCollections.

It's a straight query from database and fills the adapter. When plugging this directly to a datagridview.datasource it works.

Pulling it apart I have an issue when trying to put it into a MemorySteam giving me the error :MemoryStream' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

under the line

*new MemoryStream(img);*

**Code snipped**

```
        var rand = new Random();
        var randomCharacters = GetCompetitionCollections().AsEnumerable().OrderBy(r => rand.Next());
        DataRow randomCharacter;
        randomCharacter = randomCharacters.First();

        byte[] img = (byte[])randomCharacter[0];
        
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(img);     
        pbCharacter.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Comment: works for me https://dotnetfiddle.net/B6CcCX

Comment: Thank you, I've noticed right at the bottom of my code     internal class MemoryStream
    {
    } which obviously caused the issue.